# Is it compulsory to use templates for XSLT when converting XML to HTML?

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I apologize for asking a relatively basic question about XSLT, but I cannot find a satisfactory answer anywhere. I have tried several online tutorials (icnluding the [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_apply-templates.asp)) and Sal Mangano's [excellent book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596003722.do).

Most tutorials and explanations advice using `<xsl:template>` and `<xsl:apply-templates>`for transforming XML into HTML. However, when I am doing very simple transpositions I can achieve everything I need without templates, with only something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="...">
    <xsl:value-of select="..." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

This approach is slightly less verbose and it seems to be equally effective. However, I wonder if I am missing something. Is there any reason why I should use templates even for simple transformations? Thank you.

Comment: It is often more convenient to use separate templates, but it's certainly not compulsory. A specific example would allow a more intelligent discussion.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, thank you for your comment. Let's say that the data in your XML follows the same structure you need in the HTML file and you can do all the required transformations with a single template. Would there be any additional reason for using a template?

Comment: There might be, and there might be not. I am afraid this is too general to answer in any other way. No doubt some people will tell you to avoid `xsl:for-each` at all costs; I am not one of them.

Comment: There's another reason that tutorials emphasize the template-based approach: it's important to learn it early on. People whose experience is confined to conventional imperative languages tend to use for-each not only where it's appropriate, but also where it isn't, because they haven't troubled to learn the rule-based approach. That way, they miss out on the power of the language to do things that imperative languages can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule-based approach to transformation, using xsl:template and xsl:apply-templates, is particularly well-suited to semi-structured data in which there is considerable variation between documents, and in which you want to write code that is resilient to changes that might occur in the documents you encounter in the future. If the data is highly structured, predictable, and stable, then the for-each approach is equally effective. But XML was primarily designed for situations where the data isn't so regular.